# C#; Not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#, methods

I have been looking for a post that can actually help me figure this out, the thing is I am very new, as in within my first 30 days of seriously learning to code. Here is my code;

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string name;             //Employee Name added to nameList
        double payRate;          //Employee Pay Rate added to rateList
        double hoursWorked;      //Integer associated with how many hours the employee worked, multiplied by payRate
        bool addMore;

        List<string> nameList = new List<string>();
        List<double> rateList = new List<double>();
        List<double> hWorkedList = new List<double>();
    }

    public static object PayRollMethod(string name, double payRate, double hoursWorked, bool addMore, List<string> nameList, List<double> rateList, List<double> hWorkedList)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter employee name: ");
        name = Console.ReadLine();
        nameList.Add(name);      //adds the name entered to the namesList

        Console.Write("What is the pay rate for this employee: ");
        payRate = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        rateList.Add(payRate);  //adds the payRate to the rateList, as a double

        Console.Write("How many hours did the employee work? ");
        hoursWorked = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        hWorkedList.Add(hoursWorked);

        Console.Write("Do you need to add any other employees? Y or N");
        addMore = Convert.ToBoolean(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.ReadKey();  //holds the console open after the program finishes

    }


}
```

When I try and run it I get an error with the PayRollMethod giving me the error listed.

I think that the issue is the boolean at the bottom (addMore), I have that as it will signal the program to either restart the user input section, or prompt the user to either exit or edit an entry. I am still trying to figure out the best way to implement the loop, so I haven't typed up that part yet.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Change `public static object PayRollMethod` to `public static void PayRollMethod` (unless you plan to return an object of some kind).

Comment: I am thinking that what I will need to do is call this method in Main. I am thinking that, that is the best place to implement the loop?

However as for this topic, if I call this method in Main, do I still use void?

Comment: Well, what are the other options? Are there any?

Comment: John, thank you for the amazingly quick responses; you see all of the code that I have written currently. 

The program will save names, and pay rates to two lists, then later when the user runs a report it will print both lists in the console, and perform multiplication on the values in payRateList, and the hWorkedList.

Comment: Well I think the loop either has to go into `Main()` or go in some function that hasn't been written yet, which would be called by `Main()`. I think for this sort of problem maybe you should keep it simple.

Comment: OK, so put the loop into Main(), however when I try to call the PayRollMethod() inside Main()  it tells me "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'name' of 'Program.PayRollMethod(string, double, double, string, List<string>, List<double>, List<double>)'"

Comment: You need to supply those arguments, between the `(` and `)`, separated by commas.

Comment: I would convert this to chat but I don't enough rep yet. do I supply them where I call the method within the loop, or in the Main() parenthesis? I have the variables declared under Main(), and supplied to the PayRollMethod method. I haven't been able to find somewhere or someone to ask these questions to so I REALLY appreciate the help.

Comment: You supply them on the line that the compiler says they are needed when it reports the compilation error. If you double click the error it'll take you to it, if you are using Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared `PayRollMethod` with an `object` return type, that means you must return an object instance before you leave the method. If you don’t want to return any value, then you can declare the method with `void` return type.

Comment: Or `return null;`